# Javascript: Undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a bit of javascript that I am trying to untangle, it's on a PHP form to calculate mortgage repayments, but clicking the calculate button does nothing.

Looking at Chrome Console I get the message

> Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function" on line 10($("#form_7") to 19

of the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.ActiveButton").bind({
            mousedown:function(){
                if ($(this).attr('disabled') === undefined ) 
                    $(this).addClass('Activated');
            }, 
            mouseleave:function(){ 
                if ($(this).attr('disabled') === undefined ) 
                    $(this).removeClass('Activated');
            }, 
            mouseup:function(){ 
                if ($(this).attr('disabled') === undefined ) 
                    $(this).removeClass('Activated');
            }
        });

        $("#form_7").validate({ 
            onkeyup: false, 
            showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) { 
                if (errorList.length) alert(errorList[0].message); 
            }, 
            onclick: false, 
            rules: { 
                'Property_Price': { number: true } , 
                'Deposit': { number: true } , 
                'Duration': { number: true } , 
                'InterestRate': { number: true }  
            }, 
            onfocusout: false, 
            messages: { 
                'Property_Price': { number: "Please enter the property purchase price." } , 
                'Deposit': { number: "Please enter your deposit amount or 0 if there is no deposit." } , 
                'Duration': { number: "Please enter the duration of the mortgage." } , 
                'InterestRate': { number: "Please enter the mortgage interest rate." }  
            } 
        });

        $('#btn_4').click( function(){validate_form_7( form_7 )});
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how it can resolved?

Comment: I dont think you have imported jquery

Comment: That's possible, but usually in that case the error message is: [`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dybmn6rk/1/).

Comment: jQuery is probably there, but the validate pluging probably isn't.

Comment: Did your *calculate* button is the one with id `#btn_4`? If yes, then you are probably getting error on function `validate_form_7()`.

Comment: I think there's a required argument somewhere in the options, which you are not supplying, hence it's undefined and the error comes from inside validation plugin.

Comment: @naz : show the HTML markup...i assume issue is with `#form_7`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have **validate** defined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that your code is trying to dereference as a function something, that isn't one.

Try enabling stop-on-exception mode in your browser and see what "function" your code is trying to call when it crashes. Once you have a stack trace, it will be easier both for you to figure out, and for us to help.

Off-hand, I do not see any issues with the provided code.

Comment: Teaching how to debug doesn't provides the answer, as well.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Give a man fire and he will be warm for one night. Teach a man to light it, and he will be warm for all his life. Besides, it can be improved with additional information, and it's a second-best alternative to nothing at all - or to snide comments.

Comment: Sure, the debug part is relevant, but it still doesn't answer. I mean, a real solution with all debug advising would be perfect.